# New Silver Badge Proposal: Mega Reviewer

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-request

Mega Reviewer badge criteria:

Max out all 8 review queues in 1 day.

Comment: I would say that is far too much work for one reviewer to do in a day and would lead to people doing the reviews without due care and attention. It takes quite a long time to review queues such as the Close queue properly.

Comment: A badge exclusive to SO? (Since there's no Triage on other sites)

Comment: Relatedly, I don't think it's possible to do the max number of reviews in each queue *correctly* without running out of close votes, unless you do a lot of skipping.  Unless you're a moderator, but then technically you can't max out a queue ;-)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One of the biggest problems we have with review queues is that of [robo reviewers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155561/the-robo-approvers-are-killing-my-will-to-review-edits). Adding this badge will surely make this worse as it encourages people to chew through all the review queues to get the badge.

What we need to do is to find a way to encourage more reviewers to do careful and considered reviews i.e. broaden the review base rather than have a few people doing a lot of reviews in a mindless way.

Badges need to encourage behaviour we want that's not happening, not behaviour we don't want that already is.